# ANTLR4 Parser issues

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I'm trying to write parser for c++ style header file and failing to properly configure the parser.

Lexer:

```
lexer grammar HeaderLexer;

SectionLineComment
    :   LINE_COMMENT_SIGN Section CharacterSequence
    ;

Pragma
    : POUND 'pragma'
    ;

Section
    :  AT_SIGN 'section'
    ;

Define
    : POUND 'define'
    | LINE_COMMENT_SIGN POUND 'define'
    ;

Booleanliteral
   : False
   | True
   ;

QuotedCharacterSequence
    :   '"' .*?  '"'
    ;

ArraySequence
    :   '{' .*?  '}'
    |   '[' .*?  ']'
    ;

IntNumber
    :   Digit+
    ;

DoubleNumber
    :   Digit+ POINT Digit+
    |   ZERO POINT Digit+
    ;

CharacterSequence
    :   Text+
    ;

Identifier
    :   [a-zA-Z_0-9]+
    ;

BlockComment
    : '/**' .*? '*/'
    ;

LineComment
    :   LINE_COMMENT_SIGN ~[\r\n]*
    ;

EmptyLineComment
    :   LINE_COMMENT_SIGN -> skip
    ;

Newline
    :   (   '\r' '\n'?
        |   '\n'
        )
        -> skip
    ;

WhiteSpace
   : [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;

fragment POUND : '#';
fragment AT_SIGN : '@';
fragment LINE_COMMENT_SIGN : '//';
fragment POINT : '.';
fragment ZERO : '0';

fragment Digit
    :   [0-9]
    ;

fragment Text
    :   [a-zA-Z0-9.]
    ;


fragment False
   : 'false'
   ;

fragment True
   : 'true'
   ;
```

Parser:

```
parser grammar HeaderParser;

options { tokenVocab=HeaderLexer; }

compilationUnit: statement* EOF;

statement
    : comment? pragmaDirective
    | comment? defineDirective
    | section
    | comment
    ;

pragmaDirective
    :   Pragma CharacterSequence
    ;

defineDirective
    :   Define Identifier Booleanliteral LineComment?
    |   Define Identifier DoubleNumber LineComment?
    |   Define Identifier IntNumber LineComment?
    |   Define Identifier CharacterSequence LineComment?
    |   Define Identifier QuotedCharacterSequence LineComment?
    |   Define Identifier ArraySequence LineComment?
    |   Define Identifier
    ;

section: SectionLineComment;

comment
    : BlockComment
    | LineComment+
    ;
```

Text to parse:

```
/**
 * BLOCK COMMENT
 */
#pragma once

/**
 * BLOCK COMMENT
 */
#define CONFIGURATION_H_VERSION 12345

#define IDENTIFIER abcd
#define IDENTIFIER_1 abcd
#define IDENTIFIER_1 abcd.dd

#define IDENTIFIER_2 true // Line
#define IDENTIFIER_20 {ONE, TWO} // Line
#define IDENTIFIER_20_30   { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
#define IDENTIFIER_20_30_A   [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
#define DEFAULT_A 10.0

//================================================================
//============================= INFO =============================
//================================================================

/**
 * SEPARATE BLOCK COMMENT
 */

//==================================================================
//============================= INFO ===============================
//==================================================================
// Line 1
// Line 2
//

// @section test

// Line 3
#define IDENTIFIER_TWO "(ONE, TWO, THREE)" // Line 4
//#define IDENTIFIER_3 Version.h // Line 5

// Line 6
#define IDENTIFIER_THREE
```

With this configuration I have few issues:

1. The parser could not correctly parse "#define IDENTIFIER abcd" on line 11
2. "// @section test" on line 36 is parsed as a line comment, but I need to parse this as a separate token
3. Parsing of the commented define directive is not working "//#define IDENTIFIER_3 Version.h // Line 5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever there are problems when parsing, you should check what kind of tokens the lexer is producing.

Here are the tokens that you lexer produces:

```
BlockComment              `/**\n * BLOCK COMMENT\n */`
Pragma                    `#pragma`
CharacterSequence         `once`
BlockComment              `/**\n * BLOCK COMMENT\n */`
Define                    `#define`
Identifier                `CONFIGURATION_H_VERSION`
IntNumber                 `12345`
Define                    `#define`
CharacterSequence         `IDENTIFIER`
CharacterSequence         `abcd`
Define                    `#define`
Identifier                `IDENTIFIER_1`
CharacterSequence         `abcd`
Define                    `#define`
Identifier                `IDENTIFIER_1`
CharacterSequence         `abcd.dd`
Define                    `#define`
Identifier                `IDENTIFIER_2`
Booleanliteral            `true`
LineComment               `// Line`
Define                    `#define`
Identifier                `IDENTIFIER_20`
ArraySequence             `{ONE, TWO}`
LineComment               `// Line`
Define                    `#define`
Identifier                `IDENTIFIER_20_30`
ArraySequence             `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }`
Define                    `#define`
Identifier                `IDENTIFIER_20_30_A`
ArraySequence             `[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]`
Define                    `#define`
Identifier                `DEFAULT_A`
DoubleNumber              `10.0`
LineComment               `//================================================================`
LineComment               `//============================= INFO =============================`
LineComment               `//================================================================`
BlockComment              `/**\n * SEPARATE BLOCK COMMENT\n */`
LineComment               `//==================================================================`
LineComment               `//============================= INFO ===============================`
LineComment               `//==================================================================`
LineComment               `// Line 1`
LineComment               `// Line 2`
LineComment               `//`
LineComment               `// @section test`
LineComment               `// Line 3`
Define                    `#define`
Identifier                `IDENTIFIER_TWO`
QuotedCharacterSequence   `"(ONE, TWO, THREE)"`
LineComment               `// Line 4`
LineComment               `//#define IDENTIFIER_3 Version.h // Line 5`
LineComment               `// Line 6`
Define                    `#define`
Identifier                `IDENTIFIER_THREE`
```

As you can see in the list above, `#define IDENTIFIER abcd` is not being parsed properly because it produces the following tokens:

```
Define                    `#define`
CharacterSequence         `IDENTIFIER`
CharacterSequence         `abcd`
```

and can therefor not match the parser rule:

```
defineDirective
    :   ...
    |   Define Identifier CharacterSequence LineComment?
    |   ...
    ;
```

As you can see, the lexer operates independently from the parser. No matter if the parser tries to match an `Identifier` for the text `"IDENTIFIER"`, the lexer will always produce a `CharacterSequence` token for this.

The lexer creates tokens based on only 2 rules:

1. try to match as much characters as possible
2. if 2 (or more) lexer rules can match the same characters, the rule defined first "wins"

Because of the rules mentioned above, `//#define IDENTIFIER_3 Version.h // Line 5` is tokenised as a `LineComment` (rule 1 applies: match as much as possible). And input like `once` is tokenised as a `CharacterSequence` and not as a `Identifier` (rule 2 applies: `CharacterSequence` is defined before `Identifier`)

To have `#define` be treated the same in and outside a comment, you could use [lexical modes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#mode-pushmode-popmode-and-more). Whenever the lexer sees a `//`, it goes into a special comment-mode, and once in this comment mode, you will also recognise `#define` and `@section` tokens. You leace this mode when seeing one of these tokens (or when you see a line break, of course).

A quick demo of how that could look like:

```
lexer grammar HeaderLexer;

SPACES          : [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;
COMMENT_START   : '//' -> pushMode(COMMENT_MODE);
PRAGMA          : '#pragma';
SECTION         : '@section';
DEFINE          : '#define';
BOOLEAN_LITERAL :  'true' | 'false';
STRING          : '"' .*? '"';
IDENTIFIER      : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
BLOCK_COMMENT   : '/**' .*? '*/';
OTHER           : .;
NUMBER          : [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)?;
CHAR_SEQUENCE   : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9.]*;
ARRAY_SEQUENCE  : '{' .*?  '}' | '[' .*?  ']';

mode COMMENT_MODE;

  // If we match one of the followinf 3 rules, leave this comment mode
  COMMENT_MODE_DEFINE     : '#define' -> type(DEFINE), popMode;
  COMMENT_MODE_SECTION    : '@section' -> type(SECTION), popMode;
  COMMENT_MODE_LINE_BREAK : [\r\n]+ -> skip, popMode;

  // If none of the 3 rules above matched, consume a single
  // character (which is part of the comment)
  COMMENT_MODE_PART       : ~[\r\n];
```

and a parser could then look like this:

```
parser grammar HeaderParser;

options { tokenVocab=HeaderLexer; }

compilationUnit
 : statement* EOF
 ;

statement
 : comment? pragmaDirective
 | comment? defineDirective
 | sectionLineComment
 | comment
 ;

pragmaDirective
 :   PRAGMA char_sequence
 ;

defineDirective
 : DEFINE IDENTIFIER BOOLEAN_LITERAL line_comment?
 | DEFINE IDENTIFIER NUMBER line_comment?
 | DEFINE IDENTIFIER char_sequence line_comment?
 | DEFINE IDENTIFIER STRING line_comment?
 | DEFINE IDENTIFIER ARRAY_SEQUENCE line_comment?
 | DEFINE IDENTIFIER
 ;

sectionLineComment
 : COMMENT_START COMMENT_MODE_PART? SECTION char_sequence
 ;

comment
 : BLOCK_COMMENT
 | line_comment
 ;

line_comment
 : COMMENT_START COMMENT_MODE_PART*
 ;

char_sequence
 : CHAR_SEQUENCE
 | IDENTIFIER
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked but failed to produce the correct statement in 2 scenarios:
1.
for the text
`code
#define DEFAULT_A 10.0

//================================================================
//============================= INFO =============================
//================================================================
`code`
the first line comment appears as a token in the DEFINE statement, but the intention is to separate line comments that are not on the same line where DEFINE is mentioned.

2. NUMBER lexer is failing to tokenize single-digit numbers

Comment: You're welcome. I don't quite understand what the issue is: these comment boxes are not well suited for Q&A's. I'm sure my short demo will not handle all your cases, and after fixing the things you now mentioned, I'm sure there will be more corner cases. As I explained in my answer: begin by checking what tokens are created. Try to solve it on your own first. If you get stuck, create a new question and explain in detail what the issue is.

Comment: ok, it seems that if I move OTHER lexer bellows the ARRAY_SEQUENCE it solves the issue with single-digit number, but I'm not sure if that the correct approach here.

Comment: yeah, I will try to solve issues by myself first and will crate another question topic as a separate thread in the case I will fail to solve it. Thanks!