# Antlr Grammar for making boolean operators must if second operand exists

Tags: antlr4

If user inputs A and B, then the parsing happens correctly. But if user inputs A B (without logical operator), then parser doesnot complain about missing "AND" token.
I have tried to use this for parser rule:
booleanAndExpression
:  simpleFilter ((AND)+ simpleFilter )*                                  #SimF
;

But then parser stops considering second operand. Means if user enters "A B", AST is generated only for first operand "A" and B is not parsed.

I want the parser to complain about missing boolean operator if user enter "A B" instead of "A AND B"
ANy help would e greatly appreciated as I have been trying to resolve this but in vain

Grammar file is mentioned below

```
grammar Filter;

/* Parser rules */

filter

    :   LPAREN logicalExpression RPAREN   #ParenthesizedFilter
    |   logicalExpression EOF           #CmopositeFilterHash;

logicalExpression
       : booleanAndExpression ( OR booleanAndExpression )*                     #LogExp
       ;

booleanAndExpression
    :  simpleFilter ((AND) ? simpleFilter )*                                  #SimF
    ;

simpleFilter
    :NOT simpleFilter                                                        #NegateFilter
    | key=STR op=EQ value=(STR | DECIMAL)                                   #EqualsFilter
    |   key=STR op=NE value=(STR | DECIMAL)                                         #NotEqualsFilter
    |   key=STR op=GT value=(STR | DECIMAL)                                         #GreaterThanFilter
    |   key=STR op=GE value=(STR | DECIMAL)                            #GreaterThanEqualsFilter
    |   key=STR op=LT value=(STR | DECIMAL)                                         #LessThanFilter
    |   key=STR op=LE value=(STR | DECIMAL)                                         #LessThanEqualsFilter
    |   key=STR op=IN referenceValue                                                #InReferenceFilter
    |   key=STR op=NOT op=IN referenceValue                                         #NotInReferenceFilter
    |   key=STR op=BETWEEN fromValue=(STR | DECIMAL) AND toValue=(STR | DECIMAL)    #RangeFilter
    |   key=STR NOT BETWEEN fromValue=(STR | DECIMAL) AND toValue=(STR | DECIMAL)   #OutsideRangeFilter
    |   key=STR op=IN array                                                         #InArrayFilter
    |   key=STR NOT IN array                                                        #NotInArrayFilter
    |   key=STR op=CONTAINS value=(STR | DECIMAL)                                   #ContainsFilter
    |   key=STR NOT CONTAINS value=(STR | DECIMAL)                                  #NotContainsFilter
    |   DOLLAR LCURLY FILTER SEP id=(DECIMAL | STR) SEP name=STR RCURLY             #ReferenceFilter;

array
    :   LBRACKET (arrayItem SEP*)+ RBRACKET ;

arrayItem
    :   value=(STR | DECIMAL)
    |   referenceValue ;

referenceValue
    :   DOLLAR LCURLY type=LIST SEP id=(STR | DECIMAL) SEP name=(STR | DECIMAL) RCURLY ;


/* Lexer Rules*/

SEP: 
',' | ';';

LIST
: 'List' ;

FILTER: 'Filter';

DOLLAR: '$';
LCURLY: '{';
RCURLY: '}';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
LBRACKET: '[';
RBRACKET: ']';
GT: '>';
GE: '>=';
LT: '<';
LE: '<=';
EQ: '=';
NE: '!=';
NOT: '!' | 'not' | 'NOT';
AND: 'AND' | 'and';
OR: 'OR' | 'or';
IN: 'in' | 'IN';
BETWEEN: 'between' | 'BETWEEN';
CONTAINS: 'contains' | 'CONTAINS';
AND_MUST: 'AND';

DECIMAL: '-'? DIGIT+ ( '.' DIGIT+ )? ;
fragment DIGIT: [0-9] ;
STR: ALPHANUMERIC+ | '"' (ALPHANUMERIC | [ ] | '""')+ '"';
fragment ALPHANUMERIC: [a-z0-9A-Z!.:@#$%&^*'+/?_`~-];

WS  : [ \t\r\n\f]+ -> skip ;
```

Comment: You have `(AND)?`, not `AND`, in the third rule. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Got your point and checked without "?" but doesnot change anything.

Answer (score 1):

This grammar does not parse "A and B", let alone "A B", starting from `booleanAndExpression` or `filter`. I suspect that your driver code--which you don't provide--does not check error conditions from the parse and lex. I cannot tell the target you are using, so it is hard to know what your build environment is, and whether it is working or not. But, I would also look into that.

Here is a complete C# app with your grammar as is ([link](https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/tree/master/Filter/orig)). The driver code is generated by my Antlr4BuildTasks.Templates, and uses Antlr v4.9 and Antlr4BuildTasks, which I also wrote. The driver checks for parse errors, prints out the tokens and trees for your two examples. In both "A and B" and "A B", the parse fails. Here is the output from running your grammar on these inputs.

```
A and B
line 1:2 no viable alternative at input 'Aand'
line 1:2 no viable alternative at input 'Aand'
line 1:7 no viable alternative at input 'B'
line 1:7 no viable alternative at input 'B'
error in parse.
[@0,0:0='A',<25>,1:0]
[@1,2:4='and',<18>,1:2]
[@2,6:6='B',<25>,1:6]
[@3,7:6='<EOF>',<-1>,1:7]
( booleanAndExpression
  ( simpleFilter
  )
  ( simpleFilter
    ( STR i=0 txt=A tt=25 DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL
  ) )
  ( AND i=1 txt=and tt=18 DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL
  )
  ( simpleFilter
  )
  ( simpleFilter
    ( STR i=2 txt=B tt=25 DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL
) ) )

A B
line 1:2 no viable alternative at input 'AB'
line 1:2 no viable alternative at input 'AB'
error in parse.
[@0,0:0='A',<25>,1:0]
[@1,2:2='B',<25>,1:2]
[@2,3:2='<EOF>',<-1>,1:3]
( booleanAndExpression
  ( simpleFilter
  )
  ( simpleFilter
    ( STR i=0 txt=A tt=25 DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL
  ) )
  ( simpleFilter
    ( STR i=1 txt=B tt=25 DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL
) ) )
```

Here are a few suggestions to fix your grammar. I've made some of these changes [here](https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/tree/master/Filter/mod).

1. You should get in the habit of looking at the warning messages from the Antlr tool and address them. The [Antlr Java tool](https://www.antlr.org/download/index.html) warns `...Filter.g4:76:0: One of the token AND_MUST values unreachable. AND is always overlapped by token AND`. The rule `AND_MUST: 'AND';` can never match because the lexer always matches the first rule. Since rules `AND` and `AND_MUST` match the same string, and `AND` occurs before `AND_MUST`, it will always match, and `AND_MUST` will never match. You should remove the `AND_MUST` rule. (a) Antlr tries to match as many input chars as possible when creating a token; (b) When two or more lexer rules can match the same input, the one defined first wins.
2. Antlr parses the input string until the rule is satisfied. If a partial string works, it will do so and not complain about the rest of the input. A parse from the `booleanAndExpression`, which is not augmented with `EOF`, will parse "A" in the input "A B" and return a valid parse. To prevent this behavior, always parse with an EOF-augmented rule, e.g., `filter`. The original `filter` rule allowed partial input matching, so I adjusted the rule with parentheses (see [link](https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/blob/master/Filter/mod/Filter.g4#L5)).
3. When I read the rules for `logicalExpression` and `booleanAndExpression`, it looks like you are using factoring to set up the precedence of the OR and AND operators. But, later on, you use [alt-rule precedence](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/left-recursion.md#left-recursive-rules) for EQ, NE, GT, GE, and other operators. It looks like you copied the expression rules from two different grammars and tried to combine them for your purpose. You should choose one way or the other to set up the precedence for your operators. Factoring is easier to control, but alt-rule precedence results in smaller trees and faster parses.
4. As I mentioned before, the rule `booleanAndExpression : simpleFilter ((AND)? simpleFilter )* ;` is wrong. If you use `AND?`, then the sentential form `simpleFilter simpleFilter` is valid, so `A B` would be valid. I changed this in the modified grammar, but you can check the behavior by modifying the updated grammar I provide with `(AND)?` or just `AND?` and rerun.
5. Rule `simpleFilter` contains an error: it must include the base case for `STR`.
6. You sprinkle Antlr labels throughout the grammar. I would not recommend that you do this. It clutters the grammar and makes it unportable to other parse generators. To distinguish between one alt from another, use the Antlr accessor functions that the tool generates. For example, to distinguish between "( A )" vs. "A" in the first rule, check whether "context.LPAREN()" is not null.
7. Instead of using "-> skip" in lexer rules, use an off-channel "-> channel(OFF_CHANNEL)". This allows the error messages to avoid "run-ins", e.g., instead of `line 1:2 no viable alternative at input 'AB'`, it will appear `line 1:2 no viable alternative at input 'A B'`. However, this would require you to split the combined grammar into separate lexer and parser grammars, probably not required at this point.
8. There was another "Answer" posted after my post, which recommends adding error productions to the grammar. I would not recommend that you do this. Instead, if you want better error messages, you should modify the error reporter for the parse. You can see the example I provide. A CFG should define the language. It should not be perverted for an implementation detail.

Regards,
Ken

Answer (score 0):

1. "Complain" missing in the title, which should be rephrased.
2. The posted grammar cannot be generated :

   `warning(184): Question_OP.g4:75:0: One of the token AND_MUST values unreachable. AND is always overlapped by token AND`
3. After commenting out `AND_MUST`, given the input `A and B` :

```
  $ grun Question_OP filter -tokens input1.txt 
  [@0,0:0='A',<STR>,1:0]
  [@1,2:4='and',<AND>,1:2]
  [@2,6:6='B',<STR>,1:6]
  [@3,8:7='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
  line 1:2 no viable alternative at input 'Aand'
  line 2:0 no viable alternative at input 'B'
```

This is normal : the parser points to the token `A` and searches a rule which can match this token : filter -> logicalExpression -> booleanAndExpression -> simpleFilter :

```
 simpleFilter
     : NOT simpleFilter
     | key=STR op=EQ value=(STR | DECIMAL)
     ...
     | DOLLAR LCURLY FILTER SEP id=(DECIMAL | STR) SEP name=STR RCURLY
     ;
```

`simpleFilter` is unable to match `A`, because there is no alternative matching a single token `STR`.

4. Don't post a huge grammar with 70 % not pertinent to the question, but narrow it down to the strict minimum necessary to study the problem, like

```
 grammar Filter;

filter
    :   LPAREN logicalExpression RPAREN                      #ParenthesizedFilter
    |   logicalExpression EOF                                #CompositeFilterHash;

logicalExpression
    :   booleanAndExpression ( OR booleanAndExpression )*    #LogExp
    ;

booleanAndExpression
    :    simpleFilter ((AND) ? simpleFilter )*                #SimF
    ;

simpleFilter
    : NOT simpleFilter                                        #NegateFilter
    | key=STR op=EQ value=(STR | DECIMAL)                     #EqualsFilter
    ;

LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;
EQ     : '=' ;
NOT    : '!' | 'not' | 'NOT' ;
AND    : 'AND' | 'and' ;
OR     : 'OR' | 'or' ;
DECIMAL: '-'? DIGIT+ ( '.' DIGIT+ )? ;
STR    : ALPHANUMERIC+ | '"' (ALPHANUMERIC | [ ] | '""')+ '"' ;
WS     : [ \t\r\n\f]+ -> skip ;

fragment ALPHANUMERIC: [a-z0-9A-Z!.:@#$%&^*'+/?_`~-];
fragment DIGIT: [0-9] ;
```

Output :

```
$ grun Filter filter -tokens input1.txt 
[@0,0:0='A',<STR>,1:0]
[@1,2:4='and',<AND>,1:2]
[@2,6:6='B',<STR>,1:6]
[@3,8:7='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
line 1:2 mismatched input 'and' expecting '='
line 2:0 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting '='
$ cat input1.txt 
A and B
```

5. Now let's change simpleFilter to accept letters :

```
 simpleFilter
    : STR
    ;
```

With the following input in file `input.txt` :

```
 A and B
 A B
```

it now parses correctly :

```
$ grun Filter filter -tokens -gui input.txt 
[@0,0:0='A',<STR>,1:0]
[@1,2:4='and',<AND>,1:2]
[@2,6:6='B',<STR>,1:6]
[@3,8:8='A',<STR>,2:0]
[@4,10:10='B',<STR>,2:2]
[@5,12:11='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
```

[image: Parsing A and B A B]

The parser has no reason to complain because the input corresponds to the grammar. It is you as grammar designer who must write rules so that it refuses invalid input, something like this :

```
grammar Question;

prog
    :   ( line NL )+ EOF
    ;

line
    :   expr      {System.out.println("Found expression `" + $expr.text + "`");}
    |   a=ID b=ID {System.out.println("Hey user, you forgot the `and` between " + $a.text + " and " + $b.text + " !");}
    ;

expr
    :   NOT expr                    # ExprNot
    |   expr AND expr               # ExprAnd
    |   expr OR  expr               # ExprOr
    |   simpleFilter                # SimF
    |   LPAREN expr RPAREN          # ParenthesizedExpression
    ;

simpleFilter
    :   ID
    |   STRING
    ;

LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;
NOT    : '!' | 'not' | 'NOT' ;
AND    : 'AND' | 'and' ;
OR     : 'OR' | 'or' ;
ID     : [a-zA-Z_]+ ;  
STRING : '"' .*? '"' ;
WS     : [ \t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
NL     : [\r\n\f]+ ;
```

With the file `input.txt` :

```
A and B
A B
C or "xyz"
```

Execution :

```
$ export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.9-complete.jar"
$ alias a4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.9-complete.jar'
$ alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
$ a4 Question.g4 
$ javac Question*.java
$ grun Question prog -tokens input.txt 
[@0,0:0='A',<ID>,1:0]
[@1,1:1=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:1]
[@2,2:4='and',<AND>,1:2]
[@3,5:5=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:5]
[@4,6:6='B',<ID>,1:6]
[@5,7:7='\n',<NL>,1:7]
[@6,8:8='A',<ID>,2:0]
[@7,9:9=' ',<WS>,channel=1,2:1]
[@8,10:10='B',<ID>,2:2]
[@9,11:11='\n',<NL>,2:3]
[@10,12:12='C',<ID>,3:0]
[@11,13:13=' ',<WS>,channel=1,3:1]
[@12,14:15='or',<OR>,3:2]
[@13,16:16=' ',<WS>,channel=1,3:4]
[@14,17:21='"xyz"',<STRING>,3:5]
[@15,22:22='\n',<NL>,3:10]
[@16,23:22='<EOF>',<EOF>,4:0]
Found expression `A and B`
Hey user, you forgot the `and` between A and B !
Found expression `C or "xyz"`
```

The fact that you have defined

```
AND_MUST: 'AND';
```

lets me believe that you don't reason like the parser works, but that you want the parser behave like you think it should do !

Be patient, ANTLR is not easy. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424534/antlr4-line-comments-and-text-parsing-issue/65614331#65614331) took me about one week, and I had to do a lot of research ! Read documentation, [The Book](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference/), [documentation](https://www.antlr.org), [the tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/).

Comment: Cannot thank you enough for the response BernardK.

Comment: @virajitha Glad to be helpful !